# How to implement hierarchical model in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, hierarchical, crf

I am trying to rebuild the model featured in https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.04250.

The authors break text up into utterances (think of them like sentences), then use bi-directional LSTMs to combine these utterances, then use bi-directional LSTMs again, this time on the series of utterance representations and finish it off by using a CRF layer to predict the labels associated with every utterance.

This is a visual of the model architecture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK8Ya.png)

Here is my attempt, implemented in Keras and using the CRF layer from https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word2id) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_nr_words, trainable=False)
crf = CRF(n_tags, sparse_target=True)


utterance_encoder = Sequential()
utterance_encoder.add(embedding_layer)
utterance_encoder.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)))
#This is not the pooling used in the paper but should only affect performance:
utterance_encoder.add(AveragePooling1D(max_nr_words))
utterance_encoder.add(Flatten())
utterance_encoder.summary()


model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(utterance_encoder, input_shape = (max_nr_utterances, max_nr_words)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences = True)))
model.add(crf)
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = [crf_viterbi_accuracy])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size = 1)

# Here, X is of shape (51, 3391, 431) (51 documents featuring (max) 3391 utterances of (max) 431 words (represented by integer IDs)
# y is of shape (51, 3391, 52) (51 documents featuring 3391 utterances each corresponding to one of 52 labels)
```

Unfortunately, this fails with the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9bb38cc64dfb> in <module>
     22 #model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ["acc"])
     23 
---> 24 model.fit(X, y, batch_size = 1)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:757 train_step
        self.trainable_variables)
    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:2737 _minimize
        trainable_variables))
    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:562 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    /home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1271 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['bidirectional_2/forward_lstm_2/lstm_cell_7/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_2/forward_lstm_2/lstm_cell_7/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_2/forward_lstm_2/lstm_cell_7/bias:0', 'bidirectional_2/backward_lstm_2/lstm_cell_8/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_2/backward_lstm_2/lstm_cell_8/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_2/backward_lstm_2/lstm_cell_8/bias:0', 'bidirectional_3/forward_lstm_3/lstm_cell_10/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_3/forward_lstm_3/lstm_cell_10/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_3/forward_lstm_3/lstm_cell_10/bias:0', 'bidirectional_3/backward_lstm_3/lstm_cell_11/kernel:0', 'bidirectional_3/backward_lstm_3/lstm_cell_11/recurrent_kernel:0', 'bidirectional_3/backward_lstm_3/lstm_cell_11/bias:0', 'crf_1/kernel:0', 'crf_1/chain_kernel:0', 'crf_1/bias:0', 'crf_1/left_boundary:0', 'crf_1/right_boundary:0'].
```

Model summaries in case that helps:

```
   Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 431, 300)          2867400   
    _________________________________________________________________
    bidirectional_2 (Bidirection (None, 431, 512)          1140736   
    _________________________________________________________________
    average_pooling1d_1 (Average (None, 1, 512)            0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 512)               0         
    =================================================================
    Total params: 4,008,136
    Trainable params: 1,140,736
    Non-trainable params: 2,867,400
    _________________________________________________________________
    Model: "sequential_3"
    _________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 3391, 512)         4008136   
    _________________________________________________________________
    bidirectional_3 (Bidirection (None, 3391, 512)         1574912   
    _________________________________________________________________
    crf_1 (CRF)                  (None, 3391, 52)          29484     
    =================================================================
    Total params: 5,612,532
    Trainable params: 2,745,132
    Non-trainable params: 2,867,400
    ________________________________________________________________
```

If I replace the CRF layer with a dense layer (just for testing), a huge amount of memory ends up being used and I can't run any batch_sizes > 1. (But that is a separate issue).

Any advice/other implementations, even in PyTorch/Tensorflow if necessary would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:
https://github.com/YanWenqiang/HBLSTM-CRF features a tensorflow implementation of this model by the original authors but it is not maintained and breaks for me.

Comment: According to the documentation in the keras_contrib package, the CRF layer requires a loss of ```losses.crf_nll``` when used in join mode. You are using a categorical cross entropy loss... I suggest you either use the recommended loss function or switch to marginal model.

Comment: @PedroMarques using crf_nll unfortunately didn't work, it returns the same error described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320212/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-keras-history-using-crf. I also tried learn_mode = "marginal" but that returns a whole host of other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/xuxingya/tf2crf, which is maintained and works with tf2.